# PostgreSQL search and replace where condition

Tags: database, postgresql, replace

I am trying to save some manual time by search and replacing in my PostgreSQL database.

I have a table called `Products_Colors` where i'd like to replace all text in column `color_image` where column `color_id` is equal to 21.

```
UPDATE 
   Product_Colors
SET 
   color_image = REPLACE(color_image,"cars/car_2018.webp","cars/car_2019.webp")
WHERE 
   color_id = 21
```

Would this be correct syntax?

Comment: This could be the proper syntax. Did you actually try the query, and did it produce the expected result?

Comment: Use [Db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12) as a sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a query like this :

```
UPDATE Product_Colors
SET color_image = 'cars/car_2019.webp'
WHERE color_id = 21 and color_image = 'cars/car_2019.webp'
```