# PostgreSQL update query with condition not working

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I am having issues updating my table. My query runs successfully but updates 0 rows.

My table looks like this and is called Product_Colors:

```
createdAt    updatedAt    color_id    product_id    color_image
2019-11-25   2019-11-25   119         20            car/cars_2019_white.webp
2019-11-25   2019-11-25   119         40            car/cars_2018_yellow.webp
```

I want to change all product_id's where color_id = 119 and replace current color_image with car/cars_2019_white.webp

I have tried running, without success. 0 rows are updated.

```
UPDATE public."Products_Colors"
SET color_image = 'car/cars_2019_white.webp'
WHERE color_id = 119 and color_image = 'car/cars_2018_yellow.webp'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you get any result with `SELECT * FROM "Products_Colors" WHERE color_image = 'car/cars_2018_yellow.webp'`?

Comment: Yes. This works.

Comment: There must be something you are not telling us, because this works for me: https://rextester.com/EVOO24216

Comment: There might be a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on the table.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL search and replace where condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59040712/postgresql-search-and-replace-where-condition)

Answer (score 0):

I was targeting wrong color_id all along. Sorry.